# Why does my react code do nothing? It isn't updating the DOM

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently learning react and I'm faced with this problem.
I wrote a hello world example that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        class App extends React.Component{
            render(){
                return (
                    <div className="app-content">
                        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I open this index.html file using the VScode live server extension nothing happens in the browser. I'm using Firefox btw.

It seems like nothing is added to the `<div class="app"></div>`. I don't know why and the web console doesn't seem to give me much to work with. Anyone has any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `getElementById`, but your div has no `id`, it has a class. Change it to this:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You! I didn't realize this.